# How to use RewriteRule with different subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want to create a RewriteRule for the website but I don't know what to add.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} ="" 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.team-orbitron\.com\.?(:80)?$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1/$1 [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L] 
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN},L] 

</IfModule>
```

so when someone enters **"account.team-orbitron.com/sign-in.php"** it will search for **"/account/sign-in.php"**.

But now I want to change something with RewriteRule.

Also when someone goes to **"account.team-orbitron.com/sign-in.php"** he just need to enter **"account.team-orbitron.com/sign-in"**. I tried with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1/$1.php [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L]
```

but when someone enters **"account.team-orbitron.com"**. It will search **"/account/.php"** and I don't want that.

And I don't want to use the "fixed" code just for account..., I also want to use the code for example for blog..., forum... ect.

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure first a `.php` file exists before rewriting. Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} ="" 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.team-orbitron\.com\.?(:80)?$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ %1/$1.php [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L]
```